# What authentication credentials are required for Sql Report Services and a XML data source in Lotus Notes?

Tags: sql-server-2005, security, authentication, reporting-services, lotus-notes

We have a Lotus Notes web service that generates an XML response.  In our development environment on Visual Studio we can access the data source and run the report without issue.  When we run the report from SQL Server we get the following error:

> An error has occurred during report
>   processing. Query execution failed for
>   data set 'DataSet1'. Failed to execute
>   web request for the specified URL.

Current our SQL Server Reporting services box runs with the local system account.  Should we change this to a named account, or are we experiencing the barrier of double hop between servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web services in Notes and Domino can be secured using the standard Notes Access Control List (ACL), like all other design elements in data. What's the ACL on the NSF providing the web service? If it precludes anonymous access, that may be why you're seeing an error. You could also check the relevant Domino server's log, to see whether (a) the web service request is actually making it to the box and (b) whether any errors / access errors are subsequently thrown.

Comment: Thanks.  Our requirement is that we only certain individuals access to this report.  So Notes should NOT use anonymous access.  Our thinking is that because SSRS is executing under the local system account, it is not recognized as a domain account, and there is bounced by Notes.


We have single sign on enable for Notes and Sharepoint integration but we have the acls configure appropriately on a user by user basis.  Basically I think SSRS is not passing the domain id and attempting to login with local /  NT_Auth.